# Variant of the phrase "broad brush strokes"

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that captures the idea that one is dividing material up crudely. The context is a claim that in discussing a certain issue, we only need to make rather crude divisions (or employ simplistic categories) in order to get the point.

Obviously, painting in broad brushstrokes is pretty much this, but it would be good to use a metaphor that implies cutting/division. Closest I can think of is "rough cuts".

The sentence would look like this (with square brackets replaced):

> At this point, it is sufficient to [paint in broad brush strokes]

*Some context as requested...*

I'm writing an essay in which I draw distinctions between advertising and other activities that might involve persuasion or manipulation (public discourse, art, fundraising etc.). Obviously, there are many subtle distinctions between these activities, since they vary so much internally and between one another. But I only need to roughly demarcate some tentative boundaries between them.

Comment: *Pixelate*? *Dice*? *Julienne*?

Comment: Added a sentence example. Not sure that these terms work in such a sentence.

Comment: **Slice and dice**?

Comment: You could use the technical term ***to bucket***.

Comment: Can you supply some more context, eg what you're talking about?

Comment: At this point, it is sufficient to *divvy up* [the set] based on [criterion] into [a few bunches]. If you intend to focus on just one subset, you can *carve that one out*.

Comment: Coarsely sort or subdivide implies differentiation without hair-splitting.

Comment: My go to would be: "At this point, ***coarse-grained*** distinctions are all we need." You still get a little bit of metaphor...

Comment: @silenus This is probably the closest to what I mean

Comment: Or 'crude' - "a crude division"

Answer (score 1):

rough-hewn

> rough-hew
>   tr.v. rough-hewed, or rough-hewn
>   1. To hew or shape (timber, for example) roughly, without finishing.
>   2. To make in rough form.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rough-hewn)

I like this term because it seems to match your case. It implies getting timber that's very roughly cut, and that possibly will be refined later. So using your sentence:

> At this point, it's sufficient to make a rough-hewn drawing/plan/draft. *We can refine it later* (my addition).

Usage note: rough-hewn may or may not be understood by people whose English skills are a bit... wanting, so if you don't want to take any risk whatsoever in miscomprehension, you may want to use another term.

Answer (score 0):

You might "create a general outline" of the divisions or distinctions that you will pursue in detail later; or you might "provide a rough sketch" of the classification system you'll be presenting in its full complexity later; or you might "do an initial sort" of the data into broad categories that you will refine subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

How about *high-level*?

From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-_and_low-level):

> High-level and low-level are typically terms used to classify,
>   describe and point to specific goals of a systematic operation, though
>   its uses also vary depending on the context - such as use in computer
>   science versus business administration. In general, **high-level is used
>   to describe operations that are more abstract in nature, where overall
>   goals and systemic features are typically more concerned with the
>   wider, macro system as a whole**. **Alternatively, a low-level description
>   is one that describes more specific individual components of a
>   systematic operation, focusing on the details of rudimentary micro
>   functions rather than macro, complex processes.** Low-level
>   classification is typically more concerned with individual components
>   within the system and how they operate. [emphasis added]

In management, one often hears phrases such as "At a high level (or the highest level), such and such seems to be ...", "high-level plan ...", ... One also speaks of "keeping it out of the weeds", meaning, "Don't get bogged down in unnecessary detail. Keep it at a high level."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some sort of usage of "generalize".

Answer (score 0):

lay the groundwork

> Preliminary or basic work.
>   ‘the inquiry's findings are expected to lay the groundwork for a complete >overhaul of the system’
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/groundwork)
>
> lay the groundwork (for something)
>  To create or prepare the basics
>   or essential foundation (for something); 
> to pave the way (for
>   something)
>  [thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lay+the+groundwork)
>
> groundwork
>   (for something) work that is done as preparation for
>   other work that will be done later
>  
>   [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/groundwork)

Answer (score 0):

"At this point it is sufficient to lump [these categories] together under the umbrella term [whatever]" I'd suggest that [whatever] is something like "persuasive pursuits" because you're actually combining activities that share only a single point of similarity under a single term that is an oversimplification. You want to acknowledge that you are oversimplifying and you know it so you can break down the broad category in your later analysis.

Answer (score -1):

My dad had no small about of experience in butchering animals.  After all the nasty bits had been done, the first step would be *quartering*.  This would provide manageable chunks to divide further.  Next, he would **break down** or **debone** the quarters into sections.  Each of those would be final cut to the steaks or roasts or whatever you would see at a market.  Further cutting for finer detail would be *trimming*.

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer is that offensive; vegetarians etc. do still accept that these things happen.