# Single word for "ignoring the fine details to only consider the big picture" as a counterpoint to "pedantic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a single word to describe someone who disregards the fine details of something and only focuses on what they believe is the bigger picture? I'm looking for a pejorative connotation similar to "pedantic" which is the inverse: focusing on small details while ignoring the bigger picture.

I've tried searching here, Google, and Reddit but couldn't find anything specifically about this. I considered "ignorant", "didactic", but those are not quite right.

Comment: Related: [Variant of the phrase "broad brush strokes"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332843/variant-of-the-phrase-broad-brush-strokes) A manager at work who shows little interest in the details might be called a ***delegator***.

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances you could use **sciolist**.

> [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/sciolist)
> *sciolist*:
> One who exhibits only superficial knowledge; a self-proclaimed expert with little real understanding.

similarly:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sciolism)
> *sciolism*
> the practice of opinionating on subjects of which one has only superficial knowledge

Because these definitions involve *superficial*, they have negative connotations.

For example:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/superficial)
> *superficial*:
> If something written or said is superficial, it does not show any real understanding of the subject and does not include many details